# Bind several models to single controller method in asp.net mvc

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm implementing stateless API with bearer token auth system. What I want is to bind data from request with the way, which will be correpspond to the following signature:

`void Index(DataModel modelFromRequestData, UserModel userFromBearerToken){ ... }`

Is it possible and if yes, what is the best way to implement it? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Technically, no you can't. The reason is simple, you can only post one object in the request body.

You can however create a ViewModel that has two properties which contain your Models.

```
public class DataViewModel 
{
    public DataModel Data { get; set; }
    public UserModel User { get; set; }
}
```

and pass that to the action and get it via parameter.

However, your specific use case makes little sense. Why the hell would you want to pass the bearer token this way?

The typical way is to pass it via `Authorization` header, let your authorization middleware handle it (Identity or whatever you use), then simply access the user and his claims via the `User` property in the Controller. Don't try to reinvent the wheel :)